# What is measure of the following set?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $ D= \lbrace (x,y) \in [0,1]\times [0,1]: x-y \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace $. Is the measure of $D$ zero? Thanks.

Comment: $D$ contains $(0,0)$. so it is not empty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set $D$ is a subset of the union over $q\in\Bbb Q$ of the lines
$$D_q = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x-y=q\},$$
each of the $D_q$ having Lebesgue measure $0$ (it is an affine subspace of $\Bbb R^2$ of dimension 1).

The union being countable, $D = [0,1]^2 \cap \left(\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q} D_q\right)$ also has measure zero.

Comment: $D_q$ lying on a line. so it has measure zero?

Comment: $D_q$ **is** a line. So yes, it has measure zero in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: here we are considering $D$ as a subset of $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ . so it is a line segment. thats what I mean

Comment: Indeed, and $[0,1]^2$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @GA316: it's ok, you can also work with line segments if you prefer.

Comment: ya. Also your proof is very nice.

Comment: @Siméon:why $ D_q$ is a line?

Comment: @nim: what is the equation of a line?

Comment: @Siméon: thanks. I understand it.